# ERROR When changing password on AD with enforcing control on password history

Tags: java, active-directory, change-password

I am trying to change user's password on Active Directory, the method i'm using is this:

```
        ldapContext = getContext(resourceName);

        String quotedPassword = '"' + password.decryptToString() + '"';

        ModificationItem[] modifications = new ModificationItem[1];
        modifications[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute(PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, quotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE")));

        ldapContext.modifyAttributes(dn, modifications);
```

This works fine.

Now i want to add control on the password history, in a way that the user couldn't set the last x set passwords.

This doesn't work:

```
        final String LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID = "1.2.840.113556.1.4.2239";
        ldapContext = getContext(resourceName);

        String quotedPassword = '"' + password.decryptToString() + '"';

        ModificationItem[] modifications = new ModificationItem[1];
        modifications[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute(PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, quotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE")));

        BasicControl[] controls = new BasicControl[1];
        final byte[] controlData = {48,(byte)132,0,0,0,3,2,1,1};
        controls[0] = new BasicControl(LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID, true, controlData);
        ldapContext.setRequestControls(controls);

        ldapContext.modifyAttributes(dn, modifications);
```

Knowing that i'm using a SSL connexion, and the OID that i set is listed in the supported controls in the ROOT DSE, i am getting this error:

```
        javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

I'm stuck as i don't know exactly where the problem is comming from, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If not related to SSL, you may run into password policies in the AD environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Theo .
How do i do that? Do you suspect me not respecting the password policies in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Directory is really awful with how hard it makes it to figure things like this out, but the secret lies in the "0000052D" given in the diagnostic message. That is a reference to Active Directory system error code 0x52D, which is decimal 1325. System error codes are documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx

Obey the password policy to solve this error.

Comment: The problem was the obeiance to the password policy.
Thanks for your help